# How to ModelBind JSON to an object and nested List?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, model-binding

I'm looking to bind a JSON object to a List nested in an object.

**Background**

I have a `Category` class that contains a list of `ConfigurationFunds`:

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CountryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<ConfigurationFund> Funds { get; set; }

    public Category()
    {
        Funds = new List<ConfigurationFund>();
    }
}

public class ConfigurationFund 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CountryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ConfigurationFund()
    {

    }
}
```

The user can select a number of Funds per Category, and then I want to POST a JSON string back to my Controller and have the ModelBinder bind the JSON to the object model.

This is my Action method:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Edit(Category category) 
{
    // Categoy.Id & Categoy.CountryID is populated, but not Funds is null
    return Json(true); // 
}
```

So far, I have this jQuery:

```
$('#Save').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var data = {};

    data["category.Id"] = $('#CategorySelector').find(":selected").val();
    data["category.countryId"] = $('#CategorySelector').find(":selected").attr("countryId");

    var funds = {};
    $('#ConfiguredFunds option').each(function (i) {
        funds["funds[" + i + "].Id"] = $(this).val();
        funds["funds[" + i + "].countryId"] = $(this).attr("countryId");
    });

    data["category.funds"] = funds;

    $.post($(this).attr("action"), data, function (result) {
        // do stuff with response
    }, "json");
});
```

But this isn't working. The properties of Category are populated, but the `List<ConfigurationFund>()` isn't being populated.

**Question**

How do I need to modify this to get it to work?

**Supplementary Info**

Just to note, I've also tried to post the Category & ConfiguredFunds separately, and it works, with something similar to the following:

```
$('#Save').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var data = {};

    data["category.Id"] = $('#CategorySelector').find(":selected").val();
    data["category.countryId"] = $('#CategorySelector').find(":selected").attr("countryId");

    $('#ConfiguredFunds option').each(function (i) {
        data["configuredFunds[" + i + "].Id"] = $(this).val();
        data["configuredFunds[" + i + "].countryId"] = $(this).attr("countryId");
    });

     $.post($(this).attr("action"), data, function (result) {
        // do stuff with response
    }, "json");
});
```

In the following Action method, the ConfiguredFunds are populated, and the Category is also populated. However, the Category's List *isn't* populated. I need the Category & its List to be populated.

```
public ActionResult Edit(List<ConfigurationFund> configuredFunds, Category category)
{
    return Json(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out. I just needed to change

```
data["category.Id"] = $('#CategorySelector').find(":selected").val();
data["category.countryId"] = $('#CategorySelector').find(":selected").attr("countryId");

var funds = {};
$('#ConfiguredFunds option').each(function (i) {
    funds["funds[" + i + "].Id"] = $(this).val();
    funds["funds[" + i + "].countryId"] = $(this).attr("countryId");
});

data["category.funds"] = funds;

$.post($(this).attr("action"), data, function (result) {
    // do stuff with response
}, "json");
```

to:

```
data["category.Id"] = $('#CategorySelector').find(":selected").val();
data["category.countryId"] = $('#CategorySelector').find(":selected").attr("countryId");

$('#ConfiguredFunds option').each(function (i) {
    data["category.funds[" + i + "].Id"] = $(this).val();
    data["category.funds[" + i + "].countryId"] = $(this).attr("countryId");
});

$.post($(this).attr("action"), data, function (result) {
    // do stuff with response
}, "json");
```

Basically, I just specified that the `funds` belong to a `Category` with `data["category.funds"]`